# Concurrent server using datagrams

Tags: c, pthreads, datagram, unix-socket

A client has to send 2 strings to a server and the server has to send back a string to the client and also treat clients in parallel. The 2 entities exchange data using datagrams under Unix. My problem is that when I use threads I can't send back data to the client, nor read it. Also I can't send properly message back to client even if I don't use threads.

The server is:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int sd = 0;
void* worker(void* argm) {
    struct sockaddr_in* adress = (struct sockaddr_in*) argm;
    char s[100],s2[100];
    int adressLen;

    recvfrom(sd, s, sizeof(s), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &adress, &adressLen);
    perror("recv");
```

Perror shows recv: Socket operation on non-socket

```
    printf("I received: %s\n",s);

    strcat(s2,"sample");
    s2[strlen(s2)]='\0';
    sendto(sd, &s2, sizeof(s2),  0, (struct sockaddr*) &adress,sizeof(adress));
    perror("send");

}
```

The last `perror()` shows send: Socket operation on non-socket.
This also causes the client to wait at infinite for the string from server.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int sd;
    int servPort;

    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;  

    if (argc != 2){
        printf("usage %s <port server>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (1 != sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &servPort) || 0 > servPort || 0xffff < servPort){
        printf("%s invalid port\n",argv[1]);
        return 2;   
    }
        servPort = htons(servPort);

    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    perror("socket: ");


    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servAddr.sin_port = servPort;

    bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));
    perror("bind");


    for(;;) {
        char s[100];
        struct sockaddr_in client;
        client.sin_family=AF_INET;
        int clientLen;



        recvfrom(sd, s, sizeof(s), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &clientLen);
        perror("recv");
        printf("I received: %s\n",s);

        pthread_t thread;
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, worker, (void*) &client);
        pthread_join(thread, NULL);

        }
    close(sd);
    return 0;
}
```

What is printed in console:

```
bind: Success
recv: Success
I received: da

recv: Socket operation on non-socket
I received: `���
send: Socket operation on non-socket
recv: Success
I received: nu

recv: Socket operation on non-socket
I received: `���
send: Socket operation on non-socket
```

And the client is:

```
  #include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sd, r, lung, n;
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    struct hostent *h;
    int servPort;


    if (argc != 3){
        printf("usage %s <IP server> <port server>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    h = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if(h==NULL) {
        printf("%s: unknown host '%s'\n",argv[0],argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

        if (1 != sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &servPort) || 0 > servPort || 0xffff < servPort){
        printf("%s invalid port \n",argv[2]);
        return 2;   
    }
        servPort = htons(servPort);

    servAddr.sin_family = h->h_addrtype;
    memcpy((char *) &servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, h->h_addr_list[0], h->h_length);
    servAddr.sin_port = servPort;

    sd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    perror("socket ");


    char s[100],s2[100],s3[100];
    printf("enter text 1:\n");
    fgets(s, 101, stdin);
    printf("enter text 2:\n");
    fgets(s2, 101, stdin);

    s[strlen(s)] = '\0';
    s2[strlen(s2)]='\0';

    sendto(sd, &s, sizeof(s), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));
    perror("send");

    sendto(sd, &s2, sizeof(s2), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));
    perror("send");


    n = recvfrom(sd, s3, sizeof(s3), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &servAddr, &lung);
    perror("recv");


    printf("I received : %s", s3);

    close(sd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One problem is that you are not properly checking return values from system calls.  Most system calls return a value that indicates whether an error occurred, and only if the error occurred is it valid to do things like call `perror()`.  So, for example, you should use: `if ((sd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0)) < 0) perror("socket ");`, and then take steps to make sure that the invalid `sd` is not used again (`perror()` does not exit).

Comment: Another problem is that messages on sockets are pure binary; the strings are not null terminated unless you place a null at the end and write that as part of the message.  One oddity is the idiom ` s[strlen(s)] = '\0';` because `strlen()` stops counting at the first zero byte, so this carefully writes a zero byte over the first zero byte — and doesn't do very much that's useful (it's a no-op).  A more serious problem is: `char s[100]; ... fgets(s, 101, stdin);` because this invites buffer overflow.  You should replace the `101` with `sizeof(s)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary problem in the server is that you have a global variable `int sd = 0;` at the top of the file, that is used by `worker()`, and you have a local variable in `main()` too — `int sd;`.  The variable in `main()` is initialized to the socket; the global variable is still pointing at standard input (0), so you try a socket operation on a non-socket.

#### Working Code — `server.c`

Uses my `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` code to report errors.  Contact me by email if you want the code (see my profile).  I have not done any header minimization.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stderr.h"

int sd = 0;

static void *worker(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    socklen_t          addressLen = sizeof(address);
    char msg[100];

    printf("%s(): sd = %d\n", __func__, sd);
    ssize_t n = recvfrom(sd, msg, sizeof(msg), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &address, &addressLen);
    if (n < 0)
        err_syserr("recvfrom() (worker) failed: ");
    else if (n == 0)
        err_report(ERR_EXIT, 0, "orderly shutdown by peer\n");

    err_remark("received: (%d bytes) %.*s\n", (int)n, (int)n, msg);
    msg[n] = '\0';

    strcat(msg, ": example");
    size_t len = strlen(msg);
    if ((n = sendto(sd, &msg, len, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &address, addressLen)) < 0)
        err_syserr("error on sendto(): ");
    err_remark("sent %d bytes\n", (int)n);
    return(0);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int servPort;
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;

    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    err_setlogopts(ERR_PID|ERR_STAMP);  /* tag output with PID and time */

    if (argc != 2)
        err_usage("portnum");

    if (1 != sscanf(argv[1], "%i", &servPort) || 0 > servPort || 0xffff < servPort)
        err_error("invalid port %s\n", argv[1]);
    servPort = htons(servPort);

    if ((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
        err_syserr("error on socket(): ");

    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servAddr.sin_port = servPort;

    if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0)
        err_syserr("error on bind(): ");

    for (;;)
    {
        char msg[100];
        struct sockaddr_in client;
        client.sin_family = AF_INET;
        socklen_t clientLen = sizeof(client);

        ssize_t n = recvfrom(sd, msg, sizeof(msg), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &clientLen);
        if (n < 0)
            err_syserr("error on recvfrom(): ");
        if (n == 0)
            err_report(ERR_EXIT, 0, "orderly shutdown by peer\n");
        err_remark("received: (%d bytes) %.*s\n", (int)n, (int)n, msg);

        worker();
    }

    close(sd);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Working Code — `client.c`

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "stderr.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sd;
    ssize_t n;
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
    struct hostent *h;
    int servPort;
    socklen_t addrlen;

    err_setarg0(argv[0]);

    if (argc != 3)
        err_usage("hostname portnum");

    h = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (h==NULL)
        err_syserr("unknown host %s: ", argv[1]);

    if (1 != sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &servPort) || 0 > servPort || 0xffff < servPort)
        err_error("invalid port %s\n", argv[2]);
    servPort = htons(servPort);

    servAddr.sin_family = h->h_addrtype;
    memcpy(&servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, h->h_addr_list[0], h->h_length);
    servAddr.sin_port = servPort;

    if ((sd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0)) < 0)
        err_syserr("error on socket(): ");

    char s1[100],s2[100],s3[100];
    printf("enter text 1:\n");
    fgets(s1, sizeof(s1), stdin);
    printf("enter text 2:\n");
    fgets(s2, sizeof(s2), stdin);

    size_t s1_len = strlen(s1) - 1;
    size_t s2_len = strlen(s2) - 1;
    s1[s1_len] = '\0';  /* zap newline */
    s2[s2_len] = '\0';  /* zap newline */

    if (sendto(sd, &s1, s1_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0)
        err_syserr("sendto() (s1) failed: ");

    if (sendto(sd, &s2, s2_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0)
        err_syserr("sendto() (s2) failed: ");

    if ((n = recvfrom(sd, s3, sizeof(s3), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &servAddr, &addrlen)) < 0)
        err_syserr("recvfrom() (s3) failed: ");

    printf("Client received: (%d bytes) %.*s\n", (int)n, (int)n, s3);

    close(sd);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample Output

Trace from building the programs, running the server, and two runs of the client program.  The `-I` directory holds `stderr.h` and the `-L` directory holds `libjl.a` which includes the object file built from `stderr.c`.

```
$ make server client
gcc -O3 -g -I/Users/jleffler/inc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition server.c -o server -L/Users/jleffler/lib/64 -ljl
gcc -O3 -g -I/Users/jleffler/inc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition client.c -o client -L/Users/jleffler/lib/64 -ljl
$ ./server 12345 &
$ ./client localhost 12345
enter text 1:
Goliath Beetle
enter text 2:
Golgafrincham Excesses
server: 2013-03-25 20:51:23 - pid=10895: received: (14 bytes) Goliath Beetle
worker(): sd = 3
server: 2013-03-25 20:51:23 - pid=10895: received: (22 bytes) Golgafrincham Excesses
server: 2013-03-25 20:51:23 - pid=10895: sent 31 bytes
Client received: (31 bytes) Golgafrincham Excesses: example
$ ./client localhost 12345
enter text 1:
Small talk - what people say to each other
enter text 2:
Smalltalk - an archetypal object-oriented programming language
server: 2013-03-25 20:52:14 - pid=10895: received: (42 bytes) Small talk - what people say to each other
worker(): sd = 3
server: 2013-03-25 20:52:14 - pid=10895: received: (62 bytes) Smalltalk - an archetypal object-oriented programming language
server: 2013-03-25 20:52:14 - pid=10895: sent 71 bytes
Client received: (71 bytes) Smalltalk - an archetypal object-oriented programming language: example
$
```

Comment: Thank you so much!This really got me out of trouble.